# How to change the date/time format to English, while preserving my own country's regional settings?

Tags: 14.04, language-support, time, date

I've been using English as my system language, but Greek for regional formats.
The thing is I want the date and time to appear in English too, while *preserving* the rest of my settings in the regional format settings (e.g. euro sign for the currency, metric system etc etc).

The reason is clearly aesthetic, although I assume that for some other languages (e.g. Arabic, etc) it should be also a practical reason since the date and time in terminal would not appear correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your `~/.profile` file for editing, add this line:

```
export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
```

and relogin. That will result in date and time formats in accordance with ISO 8601. If you like those ambiguous American date formats, set `en_US.UTF-8` instead, etc.